# Converting Array of Pairs into 2 Separate Arrays Without Iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of pairs that looks like this `[[x,y], [x,y] ... ]`. I want to format it into an Object where the values are arrays of x and y values like so `{keys: [x1, x2, x3 ...], values: [y1, y2, y3 ... ]}`.

Are there any array/object operations to complete this operation without iterating through the original list?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. You can use .map to separate them, but at its core it's iterative

Comment: Any method that solves this problem uses iteration in its core

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest and safest way is to reduce the array to an object, although it requires a loop:

```js
const input = [[3, 300], [2, 200], [1, 100]];

const result = input.reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  acc.keys.push(key);
  acc.values.push(val);
  
  return acc;
}, { keys: [], values: [] });

console.log(result);
```

I wouldn't actually use the convert to object / Map method (under Original Answer), because it has a serious caveat - duplicate entries the has the same keys would be overridden.

**For example:**

```js
const input = [[3, 300], [3, 200], [3, 100]];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(input);
const result = { keys: Object.keys(obj), values: Object.values(obj) };

console.log(result);
```

### Original Answer

Building on top of [pilchard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69690628/5157454), I would convert the array to a Map, and then take the Map's keys, and values. I would use a Map, and not an object, because object's keys are always strings, and if the values are integers, the object would also be sorted by their value. A Map would preserve the original type, and won't reorder them.

```js
const input = [[3, 300], [4, 200], [1, 100]];

const map = new Map(input);
const result = { keys: [...map.keys()], values: [...map.values()] };

console.log(result);
```

An example of converting the same structure to an object:

```js
const input = [[3, 300], [4, 200], [1, 100]];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(input);
const result = { keys: Object.keys(obj), values: Object.values(obj) };

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good call, I am dealing with integers in this situation

Comment: Yep - that's what I thought when I saw `[x, y]`.

Answer (score 3):

The process is iterative, but you can hide it by using existing `Object` methods: [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
const input = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(input);
const result = { keys: Object.keys(obj), values: Object.values(obj) };

console.log(result);
```

[Ori Drori's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69690685/13762301) refinement using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is more robust not only for numeric values but for any type.

```js
const input = [[new Date(), { y: 1 }], [new Date(), { y: 2 }], [new Date(), { y: 3 }]];

const map = new Map(input);
const result = { keys: [...map.keys()], values: [...map.values()] };

console.log(result);
console.log(result.keys[0].valueOf());
```

Comment: Just one note: As a key couldn't be a number every 1st element will be converted to string even if it is a number. Otherwise it's very elegant solution which I wanted to propose, but you were the first to share.

Answer (score 1):

No space left for losers, but just another way

```js
const input = [[3, 300], [4, 200], [1, 100]];
const result = { keys: Array.from(input, x => x[0]), values: Array.from(input, x => x[1]) };
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code extracts `x` and `y` values from an array of `pairs` and organizes them into an `object` with separate arrays for `x` values (keys) and `y` values (values).

```js
const pairs = [["x1", "y1"], ["x2", "y2"], ["x3", "y3"]]

const keys = pairs.map(([x, _]) => x); 
const values = pairs.map(([_, y]) => y);

const result = { keys, values };

console.log(result);
```